# OpenStack Network not working after IPTables was turned off and then back on

Tags: iptables, openstack, openstack-nova, devstack, openstack-horizon

I installed OpenStack on RHEL6 using DevStack and had it running nicely. One day one of our "system administrators" noticed that iptables was running on the system and decided to turn it off (chkconfig iptables off). He then restarted the server and didn't tell me for a couple days. After he told me I quickly checked to see if I could access my instances. While Horizon was accessible, since nothing is being blocked, and I could access my instances from the Console, these instances could not access the network. After this I tried to access the instances from the server via SSH. The private IP was not accessible.

I then tried to restart iptables, which came up... and blocked the horizon dashboard. So I then attempted to restart all the open stack services... still no access to Horizon or any of the instances, but at least now my IPTables was populated with nova rules

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
nova-api-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
nova-network-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport dports https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport dports http 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
nova-filter-top  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
nova-api-FORWARD  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
nova-network-FORWARD  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
nova-filter-top  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
nova-api-OUTPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
nova-network-OUTPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain nova-api-FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain nova-api-INPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             devcloud.camb.comdev.ca tcp dpt:8775 

Chain nova-api-OUTPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain nova-api-local (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain nova-filter-top (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
nova-api-local  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
nova-network-local  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain nova-network-FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain nova-network-INPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:bootps 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:bootps 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:domain 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:domain 

Chain nova-network-OUTPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain nova-network-local (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

None of these rules allows allow remote access to Horizon, and they don't even allow local access to the instances that *should* be running. On top of that, before iptables was turned off I was able to allow Apache HTTPD to listen on any port, but that functionality seems to be stopped now as well.

Right now, the only thing I can think of is starting fresh because I don't have a clue where to look. I've been reading up on iptables and OpenStack and how they work together but haven't been able to find any solution. Can anyone point me in a direction that might help?

I had considered adding rules to the IPtables rules directly, but these would be overridden by nova anytime a change is made or it is restarted which would make this impossible to maintain.

Comment: Can you post the output of `iptables-save` command?

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue. I logged in the console and found that INPUT and FORWARD policies were set to drop. To fix this issue:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD ACCEPT
```

then I could `ssh` and open the dashboard.